# Gived y[n], a discret signal, using Z transform, get the general expression.

Tags: laurent-series, z-transform

i hope you can guide me in this mess i have.

Gived this signal

$y[n+2]-y[n+1]-30y[n]=(1/5)^n+1; \qquad (n \in \Bbb N, n>= 2) $

$y[0]=0,$

$y[1]=1.$

get the general y[n] expression.

Applying Z transform to all the members of the first expression I get:

$$(z^2y(z)-z)-(z*y(z))-30y(z)=\frac{z}{(5z-1)}$$

$$y(z)(z^2-z-30)-z=\frac{z}{(5z-1)}$$

$$y(z)(z^2-z-30)=\frac{5z^2}{(5z-1)}$$

$$y(z)= \frac{5z^2}{(z+5)(z-6)(5z-1)}$$

After applying partial fraction expansion I get

$$y(z)= \frac{125}{286(z+5)} + \frac{180}{319(z-6)} - \frac{5}{754\color{red}{(5z-1)}}$$

Applying Laurent to the all three roots (1/5,6,-5)

$Rmax = max \{|1/5|,|6|,|-5|\} = 6$

$A(0,6,\infty )$

-5 => $$\frac{1}{z+5} = \frac{1}{z} * \frac{1}{1+\frac{5}{z}} =\sum_{z=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{5^{n-1}}{Z^n}$$

6 => $$\frac{1}{z-6} = \frac{1}{z} * \frac{1}{1-\frac{6}{z}} =\sum_{z=1}^\infty \frac{6^{n-1}}{Z^n}$$

1/5 => $$\frac{1}{z-(1/5)} = \frac{1}{z} * \frac{1}{1-\frac{1/5}{z}} =\sum_{z=1}^\infty \frac{(1/5)^{n-1}}{Z^n}$$

Now I can get the general expression

$$Y(z) = \sum_{z=1}^\infty \frac{1}{Z^n} [ -\frac{5}{754}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1} \color{red}{\frac{1}{5}} + \frac{125}{286}*(-1)^{n-1}*5^{n-1} + \frac{180}{319}*6^{n-1} ]$$

and using

$$y(n) = -\frac{5}{754}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1} \color{red}{\frac{1}{5}} + \frac{125}{286}*(-1)^{n-1}*5^{n-1} + \frac{180}{319}*6^{n-1}$$

to prove $y[0]=0, n=0$;

$$y(n) = -\frac{5}{754}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{-1} \color{red}{\frac{1}{5}} + \frac{125}{286}*(-1)^{-1}*5^{-1} + \frac{180}{319}*6^{-1}$$

$$y(n) = -\frac{5}{754} - \frac{125}{286*5} + \frac{180}{319*6}$$

$$y[0] = 0$$

problem solved!

---

My bad, was a mistake with the (1/5) i've put in red.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the (5z-1) I've put in red. I forgot to put (1/5) after Laurent's expansion in the general expression.

peace

Answer (score 0):

$$[z^2Y(z)-z^2y(0)-zy(1)]-[zY(z)-zy(0)]-30Y(z) = \frac{z}{z-\frac{1}{5}}+\frac{z}{z-1}$$

$$(z^2-z-30)Y(z) = z(5z^2+4z-5)$$

$$Y(z) = \frac{z(5z^2+4z-5)}{z^2-z-30}$$

The degree of Numerator is greater than the degree of Denominator

$$z(5z^2+4z-5)=(5z+9)(z^2-z-30)+(154z+270)$$

$$Y(z) = (5z+9) + \frac{(154z+270)}{(z^2-z-30)} $$

$$Y(z) = (5z+9) + \frac{(154z+270)}{(z-6)(z+5)} $$

$$ \frac{(154z+270)}{(z-6)(z+5)} = \frac{A}{z-6}+\frac{B}{z+5} $$

$$ A = \frac{1194}{11}; B= \frac{500}{11}$$

$$ Y(z) = (5z+9) + \frac{(154z+270)}{(z-6)(z+5)} = (5z+9) + \frac{\frac{1194}{11}}{z-6}+\frac{\frac{500}{11}}{z+5} $$

$$y(n) = 5\delta(n+1) + 9\delta(n) +\frac{1194}{11} 6^{n-1} u(n-1)+\frac{500}{11} (-5)^{n-1} u(n-1)$$